# Ebib: note field

Tags: latex, bibtex

When I edit the `note` field, Ebib offers me to save the text in a file (linking to which I don't understand). I want to make the `note` a plain text that can be filled in as a regular field and saved in the `.bib` file, without accessing any external file. Is this possible? The manual doesn't offer any hints (I think). To clarify: I don't mean to change the behavior of the Notes that you access by pressing "N". I just want to recover the plain `bibtex` `note` field. I should add that, when I begin editing the `note` field and the text file for it is opened, the message in the minibuffer is: Wrong type of argument: number-or-marker-p, nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly you run into problems. As you mention, in Ebib you can press "N" to create a note for a bib entry and this note is stored in a separate file. Moreover, a bib entry can have a note field. To edit it, when on an entry press "e" to edit it, then navigate to the note field and press "e" to edit it. If there is no note field you can create one by pressing "a". To save your note field edits press `C-c C-c`.

Comment: I didn't realize that `note` is treated as a multiline field, which is logical. The manual only mentions `annote`.